# Showing that it is possible to Differentiate under the Integral Sign - Proof Trouble

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f: [a,b] \times [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous. Define $F(x) = \int_c^d f(x,y)dy$.

The purpose of this question is to arrive at the conclusion of being able to differentiate under the integral sign. The first part of the question asked me to show that $F$ was continuous. I've done that, but I'm stuck on this second part which is stated as so:

Prove that $F$ is differentiable and that $F'(x) = \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) dy$.

Hint: Let $\phi (t) = \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,y) dy$ and let $\Phi (x) = \int_a^x \phi(t) dt$. Show that $\phi$ is continuous and that $F(x) = \Phi (x) + \text{constant}$.

**Proving that $F$ is differentiable:**

Going back to the definition, and since this is a function in one dimension, a function $f$ will be differentiable at a point$a$ if there is a unique number $m$ such that

$$  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - mh}{h} = 0.$$

So specifically to this question I can write:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(a+h) - F(a) - mh}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_c^d f(a+h,y) dy - \int_c^df(a,y)dy - mh}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_c^d f(a+h,y) - f(a,y) dy}{h}  - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{mh}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\int_c^d \frac{f(a+h,y) - f(a,y)}{h}dy - m.$$

I want to bring the limit into the integral, but if I recall that is something that is not straightforward and needs to be proven, which we haven't done yet.

But assuming that it is permitted I would be left with:

$$\int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y)dy - m = 0$$

But now I'm left in a problem because I'm trying to show $F$ is differentiable, but I'm claiming already that what I arrived at is the needed value.

This comes up because I have to show that $F'(x) = \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)dy$.

I see where the hint is going to lead me: Showing $\phi$ is continuous and $F(x) =  \Phi(x) + \text{const}$, I would be able to use $\phi (t)$ being continuous to get $F'(x)$.

**To show $\phi (t)$ is continuous the argument would be similar to what was done for $F$:**

$$|\phi(t_1) - \phi(t_2)| = \bigg |\int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_1,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_2,y) dy\bigg| \leq \int_c^d \bigg|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_1,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_2,y)\bigg| dy \tag{$**$}$$

By uniform continuity for all $\frac{\epsilon}{d-c}$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t_1,t_2 \in [a,b]$, when $|t_1 - t_2| < \delta$ then $\bigg| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_1,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_2,y)\bigg| < \frac{\epsilon}{d-c}$.

Therefore by $(**)$ we will have:

$$\int_c^d \bigg|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_1,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_2,y)\bigg| dy < \int_c^d \frac{\epsilon}{d-c} dy = \epsilon$$

Therefore $\phi(t)$ is continuous.

I know from discussion and reading another solution, there is suppose to be some application of a chain rule, but I don't understand how it comes about. I know $F(x)$ is suppose to be some composition of functions but I don't see clearly what that composition is. I also don't understand how/why we use a parameterization in $t$.

Comment: Who says it’s supposed to be a composition? What unused letter would you nominate in place of $t$?

Comment: I was getting confused in the notation there. So because we defined $\phi (t)$ the way we have, the partial derivative with respect to $x$ in the definition of $\phi (t)$ was throwing me off. All the partial operator is signifying is that we are taking the partial with respect to the first component (in this case the $x$) at the point of $t$, but $t$ is just a dummy variable in this context. If I'm understanding it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have shown that $\phi$ is continuous and $\Phi(x) = \int_a^x \phi(t) \, dt$, it follows by the first fundamental theorem of calculus that

$$\Phi'(x) = \phi(x) := \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \, dy$$

I will use $D_1f := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to avoid confusion when $x$ is a limit of integration.  We have

$$\Phi(x) = \int_a^x \int_c^d D_1f(t,y)\, dy \, dt$$

Since the integrand is continuous we can switch the order of integration to obtain

$$\Phi(x) = \int_c^d \int_a^x D_1f(t,y)\, dt \, dy$$

Aplying the second fundamental theorem of calculus to the inner integral we get

$$\Phi(x) = \int_c^d [f(x,y) - f(a,y)] \, dy = \int_c^d f(x,y) \, dy -\int_c^d f(a,y)\, dy =F(x) - F(a)$$

and $F(x) = \Phi(x) + F(a) = \Phi(x) + constant$ as was to be shown.

Therefore,

$$F'(x) = \Phi'(x) = \phi(x) = \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,y) \, dy$$

**Alternative Approach to Justify the Exchange of the Derivative and the Integral**

Note that

$$\left|\frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h} - \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y) \, dy\right|= \left|\int_c^d \frac{f(a+h,y) - f(a,y)}{h} \, dy - \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y) \, dy\right| \\ \leqslant \int_c^d \left|\frac{f(a+h,y) - f(a,y)}{h} -  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y)\right| \, dy$$

By the mean value theorem there exists $\xi_y \in (a,a+h)$ such that $\frac{f(a+h,y) - f(a,y)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi_y,y)$ and, hence,

$$\left|\frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h} - \int_c^d \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y) \, dy\right| \leqslant   \int_c^d \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi_y,y) -  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,y)\right| \, dy$$

Now you can apply the uniform continuity of the partial derivative to show that the RHS is less than $\epsilon$ if $h < \delta$.

Comment: It may be more straightforward in your eyes, but the point of the exercise was to apply Fubini.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Does it appear to you that I missed that point with what I showed in the first part?

Comment: Of course not. I see, interestingly, that you've now chosen a different adjective :)